# Graphically outputting variables matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Can you create a GUI or some other sort of graphic that will stream output values from a loop in my code?

Comment: This question is way too vague. You need to define clearly what you want to do and if possible add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES. Check out GUIDE or MATLAB uicontrols to do so. It will use the MATLAB handles structure.